# Android Bluetooth Piconet / Scatternet protocol

Tags: bluetooth, adhoc

I am trying to develop a chat application for Android which can create piconet / scatternet networks and will be able communicate with everyone in that network. But what i do not know is which routing protocol I should use for it. Thanks for ideas.

Answer (score 1):

There have been several protocols tried out over the years. Try AODV for android.

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220308162_An_approach_to_use_FB-AODV_with_Android

[Link](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6103136)